# Commenting lines in .gitconfig instead of unsetting

Tags: git

I recently have to access git behind a corporate proxy, but the machine I am using is also one that is used outside of work hours with non-proxy networking.

I know I can use:

`git config --global --unset http.proxy` and `git config --global --unset https.proxy`

But they delete the lines. Is there a way to just comment them out, without actually having to go into the config and do it manually?

Comment: You could "go into the config and do it" _automatically_. Make a bash script or function to do it for you.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` instead? See [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpproxy).

Comment: thank you. was hoping for another argument to call but i’ll just make a script!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people out there who have the same issue / frustration. There doesn't seem to be a way to do it on the same `.gitconfig` file but there [are tools out there](https://github.com/markbattistella/gitrc) that let you switch between multiple ones.